# If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are closed paths in the plane, why is it that the path $\gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ is closed as well?

Tags: complex-analysis

I thought I had convinced myself of this but I see my reasoning (**edit: since it was asked, here's what I thought at the time: $\gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ would have to be continous and differentiable and therefore closed, otherwise $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ wouldn't be** -  *this is obviously wrong*)  was wrong. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2: [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ be two paths such that $\gamma_1(a)=\gamma_1(b)$ and $\gamma_2(a)=\gamma_2(b)$ (definition of a closed path).

We know that $\gamma_1-\gamma_2$ is a closed path since the difference of two continuous functions is continuous and $\gamma_1(a)-\gamma_2(a)=\gamma_1(b)-\gamma_2(b)$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\;\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_1(1)=p\;$ and $\;\gamma_2(0)=\gamma_2(1)=q,\;$ then $\;\gamma_1 -\gamma_2 (0)=\gamma_1-\gamma_2 (1)=p-q\in\mathbb R^2$.